# VTK: How to color a platonic solid

Tags: c++, vtk

While drawing an icosahedron (`icosahedron->SetSolidTypeToIcosahedron();`
) with VTK, I came to a point where I would like to draw it in various colours. I have tried:

```
icosahedronActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1,0,0);
renderWindow->Render();
```

but no success, the icosahedron remains as blue as it was before :(

Any tips on how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need to use a `vtkLookupTable` and apply it to your mapper.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable> lut = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>::New();
lut->SetNumberOfTableValues(n);
lut->SetTableRange(0.0, n-1);
lut->SetTableValue(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
//continue to set more values
lut->Build();

mapper->SetLookupTable(lut);
mapper->SetScalarRange(0.0, n);
```